# Python: How to check for record with the same name as a function-defined query in a JSON file

Tags: python

I am trying to get a system set up where there is a file, `students.json`, that contains a list of students. The structure will be:

```
{
    "username": {
        "l_name": "Surname",
        "f_name": "Forename"
    }
}
```

and I want to be able to have a python function, `registry()` that lets you search for a student by username, then choose either l_name or f_name as the displayed variable. But first, I want to find out if the record in question even exists and if it doesn't, exit back into my top-level function.

Comment: What've you tried?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import json
json_string = '{ "username": { "l_name": "Surname", "f_name": "Forename" } }'

def registry(username, l_or_f , reg_json):

    user = reg_json.get(username)

    if user:
        print(user.get(l_or_f))
    else:
        print('no username')

if __name__ == "__main__":
     reg = json.loads(json_string)
     registry('username','l_name',reg)
     registry('username2', 'l_name', reg)
```